# Unable to remove an item from dropdown list using javascript in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am a beginner to javascript. I am trying to remove few items from the dropdown list based on an option button. In firefox, I see that it is reaching the line to remove the item, but not deleting the item. Can you please help on this?

```js
disable_dropdown_items() 
{
 var yes = document.getElementById('RadioYes').checked;
 var all_opts = document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS').options;
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS').options.length; i++) 
 {
  if((document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS').options[i].value == '891') && (yes == true)) 
  {
      document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS').options[i].remove(i);
  }
    }
}
```

The line,

```js
document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS').options[i].remove(i);
```

works well in IE and chrome and removes the value "891", but firefox doesn't remove. Am I missing anything here?
I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS').options.remove(i);
```

without the index for options, still no luck.

Comment: are you 101% sure that the element with id `ALL_ITEMS` is UNIQUE?

Comment: try this `document.getElementById("ALL_ITEMS").remove(i)`

Answer (score 1):

A much smaller version would be to do it like this. Use [remove() on select](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp).

```
function disable_dropdown_items() {
    var yes = document.getElementById('RadioYes').checked;
    var sel = document.getElementById('ALL_ITEMS');

    for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++) {
        if ((sel.options[i].value == '891') && (yes == true)) {
            sel.remove(i); //Remove from select using index
        }
    }
}
```

An example ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywhkexL9/)***.

Answer (score 0):

This removes the third option i.e. Rejected

```
<select id="FilterByTypeTop" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Approved</option>
    <option value="2">Not Approved</option>
    <option value="3">Rejected</option>
</select>
<script>
    $('#FilterByTypeTop').find('option[value="3"]').remove();
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Thank you for giving an answer to this question. However your answer is using the jquery framework, it would be more helpful if you edit your answer to explain how to do this with pure javascript as the OP has asked. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for how to write a good answer.